# R Development Tools do not install properly

Tags: r, devtools, rtools

I'm attempting to get started with packaging a few scripts I've developed for my personal use using the package development book at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/intro.html. I keep running into problems getting the development tools installed, which has proved very frustrating.

This is for R ver 3.4.4, which is already setup to work with knitr and rmarkdown for generating reports. It is on a company network and computer, which puts the network largely out of my control.
I do have RTools (v.3.5.0.4) installed, which is in the same directory as RBuildTools.

When running 'has_devel()', I encounter a loop wherein Rstudio attempts to install RBuildTools, completes with no errors or notifications, but when re-checking 'has_devel()' it attempts to install it again.

I've gone through the list of https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/234 but none of the solutions have worked.

## Session info

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4    yaml_2.2.0    
[4] xfun_0.5
```

```
> library(devtools)
> has_devel()
Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
> has_devel()
trying URL 'https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 108622512 bytes (103.6 MB)
downloaded 103.6 MB

Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
> has_devel()
Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
```

Following up on the 'could not find tools' notice, I attempted to load all devtools

```
devtools::load_all()
Error: No root directory found in \\USERSTORE/02/5028/Documents or its parent directories. Root criterion: contains a file `DESCRIPTION`
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="\\USERSTORE": The specified path is invalid
2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="\\USERSTORE": The specified path is invalid
```

I'm only trying to setup this environment so that I can begin a simple packaging process.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and it was due to the fact that my library install path was defined on a network drive. It looks like the directory for your libraries either doesn't exist, or you don't have the privileges to view them.

You can try changing this by the `.libPaths()` function, before you run the install command.